# How does MessageBoxIcon Enumeration manage to have Error as part of it

Tags: vb.net

I would like to create an Enumeration, one item of which would be Error.  As Error is a keyword the compiler, as expected, points out that that is not on.  As I have Option Strict On on by default I thought that possibly this would be one instance where setting it specifically to off would help.  However it doesn't.

So put very simply how does the MessageBoxIcon manage to use Error as an item in its enumeration?

Comment: Because it was written in C#, not VB.NET. No problem in C# of course, Error is not a keyword in that language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose the Error keyword in square brackets

```
Public Enum SimpleSettings
    [Error] = 0
    Warn = 1
    Correct = 2
End Enum
```

From the [VB.NET Language specifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711644%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> Regular identifiers may not match keywords, but escaped identifiers
>   can. An escaped identifier is an identifier delimited by square
>   brackets. Escaped identifiers follow the same rules as regular
>   identifiers except that they may match keywords and may not have type
>   characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Public Enum Foo
    Bar
    Faa
    [Error]
End Enum
```